# Grails 2.5.0 - integration testing with spring security for RESTful service

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to test the security of a Grails web app, making sure only certain roles can POST and that the proper responses are given. I have the following in an integration test:

```
class MyIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def grailsApplication
    def testdataService

    def setup() {
        testdataService.addTestData()
        SpringSecurityUtils.reauthenticate 'user1', null
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test case"() {
        given:
        RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

        when:
        RestResponse response = rest.post("http://localhost:8080/${grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'}/mycontroller/myaction") {
            json([
                    data1: "foo",
                    data2: "bar"
            ])
        }

        then:
        response.status == 200
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the integration test is run before Spring Security starts up, and I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8080/myapp/mycontroller/myaction":Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException
```

How can I get my integration tests to run so I can test the experience, especially security, of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server isn't started for integration tests. The Spring application context is started, plugins are active, there's a real database available (by default in-memory, but you can configure it to point to a server), etc. but no web server.

You need to use functional tests if you want to test security and other functionality that requires a running web server. I've used http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test and it's pretty good, but somewhat buggy. I used version 1.2.7 but I see that there's now a 2.0 version, so that might work better.